# Join attributes by location error

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I'm trying to join attributes by location - my Join layer is one I created from a 10m fixed width buffer, my geometric predicate is only 'within'.  When I run the algorithm, I get an error of "-2147483646 See log for more details".  If I reverse the parameters and use my Join layer as the target and use 'contains' instead of 'within', the algorithm runs as expected (but then I'm not getting the values on the layer I want...)

I've read other articles on here and tried the suggestions (check geometries) but with the same results.

Answer (score 3):

Found the error - I have to specify an output for the Joined Layer, if I leave it blank to create a temporary layer, I get the error.  If I give it an output, it works.